# Appveyor cannot upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, appveyor

I've got a S3 access key and secret set up. I've tried the credentials locally with the aws cli program. However, when run on Appveyor it got permission denied as follows

`Deploying using S3 provider
Uploading artifact "NOpenType/bin/Release/NOpenType.0.1.4-ci0187.nupkg" (25,708 bytes) to S3 bucket "nrasterizer-artifacts" as "master/NOpenType/bin/Release/NOpenType.0.1.4-ci0187.nupkg"
Access Denied`

How do I resolve this and let appveyor upload to my bucket?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to any number of reasons

1. Is S3 provider properly configured? Obvious, but please recheck the key& secret and bucket names etc.
2. Does the user have appropriate permissions? You did mention that you tested the credentials locally. But it  could be that  there is a S3 bucket policy which restricts uploads etc. to a set to specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As I was using `set_public: true` setting I needed the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission in addition to `s3:PutObject`.